# Manim (manimlib version) not working as it should

Tags: python, manim

Everything seemed to be installed correctly, and when  launch rendering, I get this error:

```
File "c:\users\oussa\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\manimlib\extract_scene.py", line 155, in main
    scene = SceneClass(**scene_kwargs)
  File "c:\users\oussa\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\manimlib\scene\scene.py", line 75, in __init__
    self.construct()
  File "testM.py", line 5, in construct
    text = TextMobject("I literally h8 u.")
  File "c:\users\oussa\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\manimlib\mobject\svg\tex_mobject.py", line 150, in __init__
    self.break_up_by_substrings()
  File "c:\users\oussa\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\manimlib\mobject\svg\tex_mobject.py", line 190, in break_up_by_substrings
    sub_tex_mob.move_to(self.submobjects[last_submob_index], RIGHT)
IndexError: list index out of range
```

And that's the Python code of the program running:

```
from manimlib.imports import *

class TestScene(Scene):
  def construct(self):
    text = TextMobject("I literally h8 u.")
    text.scale(2)

    self.play(Write(text))
    self.wait()

class TestScene2(Scene):
  def construct(self):
    text = TextMobject("I literally $$3 u.")
    text.scale(2)

    self.play(Write(text))
    self.wait()
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't actually do anything, as it's just a bunch of class definitions. By the way, you probably want to start using standard Python indents of 4 instead of 2, it'll save you headaches later.

Installing `manim`, your code doesn't actually work, but if the import statement is replaced with `from manim import *`, you instantiate an object and replace the `TextMobject` with `Text`, it runs and renders some videos after calling `construct()`.

I replaced it with a more focused import as doing a `import *` is generally a bad idea.

```
from manim import Scene, Text, Write


class TestScene(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        text = Text("I literally h8 u.")
        text.scale(2)
    
        self.play(Write(text))
        self.wait()

class TestScene2(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        text = Text("I literally $$3 u.")
        text.scale(2)
    
        self.play(Write(text))
        self.wait()


ts = TestScene()
ts.construct()
```

I was using Python 3.9.7 (no reason, just the version my environment had) and manim 0.12.0.

I'd say `manim` looks like a pretty janky package though, so I'd expect some more weird issues.

Comment: Actually, i was working with a different version of manim that works differently, from the community version (and it's probably outdated). When i installed the community version everything worked as expected.